# 'TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'title' of 'notifsDto' as it is undefined'

Tags: nestjs

Please how do i solve the error above. It's giving me quite the headache cause everything looks fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below are code snippets of my repository class, my dto class and my log.

[My Repository class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aePJr.png)

[My Dto class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRyb9.png)

[My system logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ura8.png)

Comment: Hi, could you please copy and paste your code into the question and wrap it in triple backticks so it is easy to read & copy/paste? `\`\`\`<code>\`\`\``

Comment: noted, subsequent questions will be done in that format. thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is that the title is without values (empty) actually it's look like that whole your `dto` are empty and because the title is the first one it checked first .
here is some solutions

1. if you using postman to post the `dto` values try to use `json`
   form 2-check if you pot `@Body()` befor dto in method handler in you
   controller  for example : `someMethod(@Body() notifsDto:NotifsDto){}`.
2. add `@IsString()` above the "title"
   attribute in `dto`

Comment: hi, thanks! the problem was I forgot to add @Body() in my controller and @IsString() in my dto class. thanks, it works

Comment: Bro! I'm have the same problem, but I added the '@Body' in my 'Controller'. In my 'LogInterceptor' I receive the 'body request', but in my controller it's 'undefined', no make sense :/